# JavaFX FXML invalid type

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml

I'm writing a JavaFX application with Eclipse in Linux and, using SceneBuilder, I work out a certain FXML code.
When I move to windows, if I try to execute the code it runs fine but if I try to modify the fxml file it starts to give me an error (not related to the modifications). I also tried using NetBeans but nothing changed.

The error is :

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Light.Distant is not a valid type.
```

while the code giving error is:

```
                <Circle fx:id="check_credit" centerX="195.0" fill="#0d6615" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="150.0" radius="8.0" stroke="TRANSPARENT" strokeLineCap="ROUND" strokeType="INSIDE">
                 <effect>
                    <Lighting bumpInput="$null">
                       <light>
                          <Light.Distant />
                       </light>
                    </Lighting>
                 </effect>
              </Circle>
```

What could be the cause? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the import from your FXML file:

```xml
<? import javafx.scene.effect.Light.Distant ?>
```

Comment: I'm using `<?import javafx.scene.effect.Lighting?>` that was automatically added by SceneBuilder

Comment: Yes, but that is not going to import `javafx.scene.effect.Light`. You need both.

Comment: Try updated version. FXML is kind of of weird with inner classes

Answer (score 1):

Ok I fix it using

```
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
```